# Process builder cannot evaluate formula field

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, field-update, scheduled-job, process-automation

I have the following formula field 'Payment Status' that checks if an invoice is paid or not:

[image]

I have a process builder that checks if the value of the payment status is 'Unpaid', it schedules some actions:

[image]

When the payment status is changed from 'Unpaid' to 'Paid', I want to remove the scheduled actions from the paused flow interview, but I can still see the actions there. How can I make the process remove the actions from the paused flow interviews when status is changed to 'Paid'?

Comment: does the formula rely on changes in records other than the target record of the process?

Answer (score 1):

Because the way that Formula fields work (they are processed last or nearly last in the chain) you cannot use them to properly control your process.

Code the formula in your process.

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide some details. What do you mean by code the formula?

Comment: In the image that you added, I can see blng__Invoice Equals String "Unpaid". Under there add the individual rows of the formula.

Comment: And what should I write in the formula?

Comment: If your users need to see it, or if you do, leave it unchanged. If it is unnecessary then delete it. I would keep it for a while even if it is isn't